# Something wrong with RectangleChart and Tooltip?

Tags: graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 and fixed in 10.1 or earlier**

---

Currently I'm working on a diagram showing the merit order of power plants in the Netherlands. On the horizontal axes you see the cumulative power and on the vertical axes you see the costs per MWh. The cheapest units on the left and the more expensive to the right.

The function `RectangleChart` looks just fine to make this diagram. The width is the maximum power of each power plant and the hight is the cost/MWh. There are a lot of units and that's why I would like to use the Tooltip wrapper to display the power plants name when I hover the mouse cursor over the rectangle.

When i use:

```
RectangleChart[Tooltip[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, "test"]]
```

I get two rectangle bars and, when I hover over them, I get the Tooltip "test". But when i use:

```
RectangleChart[{{1, 1}, Tooltip[{2, 2}, "twee"]}]
```

the second rectangle bar does not show. When I wrap also the `{1, 1}` with `Tooltip`, I get the error message:

> RectangleChart::ldata : {{1, 1}, {{2, 2}} is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.>>

When I add a third rectangle bar and wrap it with `Tooltip`, all seems to be OK again.

```
RectangleChart[{Tooltip[{1, 1}, "een"], Tooltip[{2, 2}, "twee"], Tooltip[{3, 3}, "drie"]}]
```

I'm using *Mathematica* version 9, on a MAC OSX 10.8.3.

Do you see the same behavior when using only two rectangle bars in `RectangleChart`?

Comment: I get the same results. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This works as expected in version 7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I tested with V9.0.1. I can't imagine what WRI did that screws up with exactly two data points.

Comment: @m_goldberg actually that's pretty easy; if you use an unrestricted pattern like `{x_, y_} :> . . .` intending to operate on the integers in `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}` you hit a corner case with `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` wherein `x_` matches all of `{1, 2}` and you get a bug.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. +1 on your analysis, but one would think the WRI developers are good enough to avoid the pitfall you describe. I guess they're only human, after all.

Comment: @m_goldberg There is a lot of code in play, and sometimes the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing.  I suspect that the handling of `Tooltip` was unaccounted for; *if* such a pattern is at fault it presumably cannot match in normal circumstances, so whatever format is internally produced when using `Tooltip` is nonstandard in terms of what the pattern-writer was anticipating.

Comment: I have received confirmation from WRI that this is a bug that surfaced in V9.0.1.

Comment: I suspect this bug was fixed in 10.0, but cannot check with that version right now. I have written the bug header with the bugfix version 10.1. Could someone else please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explore your problem, I defined the following functions

```
data[n_Integer?Positive] := RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {n, 2}]
labels[pre_String, n_Integer] := DictionaryLookup[pre ~~ ___ ~~ "ing", n]
tt[n_Integer?Positive] := MapThread[Tooltip, {data@n, labels["tw", n]}]
```

With these I could quickly generate a large number of test cases.

```
Quiet@Table[RectangleChart@tt@k, {k, 12}]
```

[image]

Every chart that actually plotted had the correct set of tooltips. It looks like you will be all right if don't have exactly two data points.

P.S. I have reported this to WRI tech support as a suspected bug.

#### Update

I have received a response from WRI tech support confirming this a bug that surfaced in V.9.0.1. Here is the relevant section of that response:

> I have reproduced this problem with Tooltip and RectangleChart and agree
>   that there is some unintended behavior here.  It appears that everything
>   was working as recently as Mathematica 9.0.0, but that this does [not] work
>   properly with lists of 2 Tooltips in 9.0.1.
>
> I have filed a report with our developers on this issue.

Comment: Because of the large number of data points, i have a lot of power plants, in practice the "bug" did not hurt to much. Thanks for reporting it to Wolfram.